# How do I create interruptible sleep in Windows with C?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi

I want the current thread to sleep for a given time. However, another thread should be able to interrupt it and wake it up early. In unix this is fairly simple using `sleep` + `pthread_kill`. In windows there is `SleepEx` and `SleepConditionVariableCS`. SleepEx doesnt seem to actually cause the thread to sleep since it is still processing events, so would sleeping on a condition variable be a better solution? Furthermore, it is somewhat unclear to me how to wake a thread sleeping with SleepEx. What is correct solution to this problem, `SleepEx` or `SleepConditionVariableCS`? (Also, could you point out how to wake a thread sleeping with `SleepEx`? The MSDN documentation is very confusing.

Comment: How to wake a thread with `SleepEx`: `SleepEx(duration, TRUE);` + [`QueueUserAPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684954(v=vs.85).aspx). This is close to to the `sleep` + `pthread_kill` mechanics. Martin James' answer is the simple and idiomatic answer though IMO (and supports more versions of Windows compared to SleepConditionVariableCS).

Comment: SleepEx really does sleep, although in some circumstances (mostly if you are doing asynchronous I/O in this thread) it might be woken up prematurely.  I don't believe there is any significant loss of efficiency.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a manual reset [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and wait on it with [`WaitForSingleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - has a timeout parameter. See MSDN for details.

Comment: I have used CreateEvent and WaitForSingleObject() on c-only projects. Also I have used the kernel-mode equivalents for device drivers and confirm that his is the way to do it. +1

Comment: @chacham15: read "ManualResetEvent" as "manual reset event". It is not a class, it is API + handle, fully C compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @RomanR.  I use several different languages/build environments and I was not specific enough with the Windows API calls, (that, and C# classname - oops!).

Comment: Oh great, a polling/timeout solution ;-)